# Como salvar registros de uma consulta mysql em C++

Tags: mysql, c++, mingw

Estou utilizando uma biblioteca em C++ que faz a consulta no banco de dados. Meu objetivo é fazer uma consulta, e salvar os dados em um arquivo txt, talvez até manipulando para ficar no formato json. O problema está que nao consigo recuperar o valor dos registros ao salvar o arquivo. Quando adiciono o valor row[i] , ele salva um valor binário, ao invés de caracteres ASCII. Aparentemente, mesmo se fosse em ASCII, duvido que retornaria o conteúdo do campo, visto que a função mysql_fetch_row provavelmente não faz isso. Não consigui achar alguma função fetchArray se é que exista. Segue o código

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

#define HOST "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASS ""
#define DB "estoque"


MYSQL *conn;


int main()
{

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);



    if(mysql_real_connect(conn, HOST, USER, PASS, DB, 0, NULL, 0))
    {
        cout << "conectado \n";

    }
    //Select all table
    mysql_query(conn,"SELECT * FROM estoque"); 

    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "SELECT %s from %s", value, table);

    mysql_real_query(conn, buf, strlen(buf)); 

    // pointer of result
    MYSQL_RES *result; 

    MYSQL_ROW row; 
    unsigned int i;


    result = mysql_store_result(conn); 
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);


    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) 
    {   
    for (i=0; i<mysql_num_fields(result); i++) 

        cout << row[i] << endl;

    //  ############### ESCREVER EM ARQUIVO DE TEXTO O RESULTADO ############################

        std::ofstream Hypnos_FILE;
std::string TEXTO = row[i];
Hypnos_FILE.open("resultado.txt", std::ios::app);
if (Hypnos_FILE.is_open())
{
   std::cout << "Arquivo de texto aberto com sucesso!\n";

   Hypnos_FILE << TEXTO;

}
else
   std::cout << "Erro ao abrir arquivo de texto.";

Hypnos_FILE.close();                

    //  ############### ESCREVER EM ARQUIVO DE TEXTO O RESULTADO ############################

    } 
    // mysql_query(conn,"SELECT varchar1, varchar2 FROM estoque;");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse código nem compila.

Comment: Tem que instalar a biblioteca libmysql

Comment: Depois jogar a dll na pasta system32 do windows

Comment: Ele não compila, ele tem erros básicos, o problema não é esse, nem chega nesse ponto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa verificar os valores de retorno adequadamente, começando pelo `mysql_init()` e `mysql_real_connect()`, e abortar o programa caso seja necessário. Se isso não acontecer o resultado pode ser inesperado e pode acarretar na gravação de dados inválidos em seu arquivo assim como já está acontecendo.

Em segundo você está descartando a primeira linha da tabela, pois há uma chamada à função `mysql_fetch_row()` ao relento.

Por último, e talvez a real razão do seu problema, você está usando o índice (variável `i`) com um valor inválido, acarretando um *buffer overflow*. Basta colocar a escrita do arquivo dentro do escopo do seu laço `for` para resolver este problema.

Segue abaixo um código simples que funciona como você provavelmente deseja:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <string.h>

#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

#define HOST "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASS ""
#define DB "estoque"

MYSQL *conn;

int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!conn) {
        cout << "falha no mysql_init()" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, HOST, USER, PASS, DB, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!conn) {
        cout << "falha no mysql_real_connect()" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "conectado" << endl;

    const char *value = "*";
    const char *table = "banana";
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "SELECT %s from %s", value, table);
    mysql_real_query(conn, buf, strlen(buf));

    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(conn);

    std::ofstream Hypnos_FILE;
    Hypnos_FILE.open("resultado.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (!Hypnos_FILE.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Erro ao abrir arquivo de texto.";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Arquivo de texto aberto com sucesso!\n";

    unsigned int j = 0;
    while (((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) !=NULL)) {
        cout << j << ":";
        Hypnos_FILE << j << ":";;
        j++;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(result); i++) {
            cout << " " << row[i];
            Hypnos_FILE << " " << row[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
        Hypnos_FILE << endl;
    }

    Hypnos_FILE.close();

    mysql_close(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Isso solucionou o problema.
Só tive que dar uma adaptada no código. Segue o gist da versão do seu código que solucionou o problema:
https://gist.github.com/paulosergioduff/de93765365eafdaad71c5ea52a82ff0e

Comment: Tome cuidado, pois agora você não está jogando fora apenas o primeiro valor da consulta, mas também o segundo. Recomendo que você dedique bastante a entender como está funcionando os laços do seu código.

Comment: Vou dedicar. Mas curiosamente retornou todos os registros. Mas vou ter cautela!